# Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI will be retired in November 2023

Tags: django, azure, docker, docker-compose

I try to deploy a docker django container to the Azure cloud. And so I login in with:

```
docker login azure. And I am logged in.
```

SO I am in the local directory wheren the application files are stored. And I try to build the docker image:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build
```

But then I get every time this message:

```
(env) PS C:\repos\DWL_backend_Rachid> docker compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build
Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI will be retired in November 2023. Learn more: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-ecs-eol/
```

And I can not build or run.

I searched for this of course. But I can not find any thying how to tackle this.

And I also updated the docker desktop.

Question: how to handle the message: `Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI will be retired in November 2023. Learn more: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-ecs-eol/`

Comment: Yesterday it was working fine. And now I can not use docker-compose??

Comment: Can somebody explain what is wrong? Why this doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do much to handle that message: they are moving from the docker cli to other projects, such as [compose-ecs](https://github.com/docker/compose-ecs) for AWS ECS.

Since you're on Azure, you should try to use the `Azure CLI` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ to deploy your application. [Here a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) about deploying a containeraized app on Azure.

You can also follow this discussion to keep updated about what's going on  https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/2258

Comment: @Alez.Ahh, Oke. Thank you for you explanation. But I have it now also local. So I try to run docker containers local with the same cmmand: docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build 
Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI will be retired in November 2023. Learn more: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-ecs-eol/. But oke. I understand now. They are bussy with it... I didn't understand that.

Comment: If you want to deploy on Azure, at the end, it does not change much for you: you only need to re-create the docker-compose-deploy.yml on the Azure CLI and build it with the same command. But, yes, you cannot deploy locally or on Azure from the same CLI.

Comment: @Alez.Yes, oke. But I am now not signed in in azure or docker azure. So just local. ANd I try  docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build  but I still get this message: Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI will be retired in November 2023. Learn more: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-ecs-eol/ and nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry @mightycodeNewton, this is not possibile. Are you sure you didn't login to Azure or redirect to Azure?

Comment: @Alez.I just started powershell. went to the direcotory: C:\repos\DWL_backend  docker logout azure and  docker logout crdierenwelzijn.azurecr.io then did a  docker compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build  and nothing happens.  Everything was working fine, till today .

Comment: @Alez.Oke, it was about the context. I was not in the default context.  Now it works again on local. But if I am logged in in azure it doesnt work: I created a context:  dierenwelzijncontext and I do docker context use dierenwelzijncontext and  a  docker compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this makes more sense. Try Azure cli to deploy on Azure.

Comment: @Alez does this imply that `docker compose` won't be able to run `ECS` contexts anymore, or just that it will be discontinued in terms of maintenance?

Comment: You can continue to use docker compose to run on ECS but from this tool https://github.com/docker/compose-ecs. Not sure, I guess the maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume they discontinued it, because the native https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli tool can deploy compose files itself.